# FPDF and page break

Tags: php, fpdf

I am generating a PDF in landscape showing 9 columns on each line. I am using these settings:

```
parent::__construct($orientation = 'L', $unit = 'mm', $size = 'A4');
$this->SetDisplayMode(100);
$this->setAutoPageBreak(true, 15);
$this->setMargins(0,18);
$this->AliasNbPages();
$this->AddPage();
```

As soon as the end of page one is reached, on top of page two the first cell is printed. Nothing else!? On page three, the second cell is printed and so on until page 10, where column 9 is printed and all the other lines - the following rows are complete and all on page 10. Each of this "lonely" cells is at its right position. The only problem is, they should be on the SAME page.

Can anybody tell me where my mistake is hidden?

Thx
Oliver

Comment: Please share more details. The given code does not look like valid PHP code, it is missing a lot of context that could help others to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that FPDF seems not to be able to make a proper page break when you use SetXY().
I now look for the actual GetY() and when this gets to big I use an AddPage() and reset y to a fitting value.
Following is the relevant code for filling the lines (HTH):

```
    foreach ($daten as $datum) {
        $this->SetXY(5,$y);
        $this->Cell(20, 4, strftime( "%d.%m.%Y", strtotime($datum["date"])), $border);
        //.......  some more code
        $this->SetXY(261,$y);
        $this->Cell(25, 4, number_format($datum["rate"], 2, ",", "." ) . iconv( 'UTF-8', 'windows-1252', " €" ), $border,0,"R");
        //make corrections in case of a MultiCell-line - there MAY be two of them
        if ($y2 > $y+4 OR $y3 > $y+4) {
            if ($y2 > $y+4) {
                $y = $y2+1;
            } else {
                $y = $y3+1;
            }
        } else {
            $y = $this->GetY() + 5;
        }
        if ($y > 190) {                                             //do we need a new page?
            $y = 22;
            $this->AddPage();
        }
    }
```